# nodeJS route all request

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am writing a nodejs application.
I want to to route all the requests to some common API. For that I am using

```
 app.get('*', function(req, res) {
   /* Do Something */
 });
```

In "Do Something" Section I want to retrive the req.route.regexp and then based on that I will do processing. I am expecting req.route.regexp should be the exact URL's regexp for which we came here. But as I am handling this in '*', so regular expression is not giving me equivalent req.route.params.

So is there any way to get the regexp based on req.route.params in app.get of all routes (*).

Ex: I have url as: "/:val", for that I am expecting regexp 
"/^/(?:([^/]+?))/?$/i", but I am getting regexp for "*", 
so how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

When the handler of `app.get('*', ...)` is called, the eventual route hasn't been matched yet and express cannot possibly tell you about a subsequent route.

The only solution that I see would be to manually call a handler in all your routes:

```
app.get('/:val', function (req, res) {
   if(!myGlobalHandler(req, res))
     return;
});

function myGlobalHandler(req, res) {
  if(somethingWrong(req)) {
    res.send({error: 'uh oh...'});
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

If you tell me more about your use-case, maybe there's a more elegant solution.